# 4-bit Register with Four Operations

Tags: shift-register, register

I'm given a task to design a 4-bit register using D Flip-Flops (and MUXes) that operates according to the following selection inputs:

When..

S1S0 = 00, No Change;

S1S0 = 01, Register is Cleared to 0;

S1S0 = 10, Current State is Complemented;

S1S0 = 11, Parallel Data is Loaded.

Below is what I've made, but I'm not so sure if I've implemented it correctly.

Could you correct me if there's anything that's incorrect or that I should improve?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The circuit you implemented will work properly for all the cases you stated except for the last one. For `S1S0 = 11`, it will perform shifting and serial data loading.

For parallel data loading, you must connect the `I_3` lines of your MUX to the *parallel-data-in* lines (4-bit).

[image]

Image courtesy: @IANIK

Comment: So, is it how I do parallel loading?
http://s22.postimg.org/ik2ucou3l/Untitled.png

Comment: @IANIK Yes. And I am adding your picture to the answer.